# Error Code: 1072. Key column 'noteid' doesn't exist in table

Tags: mysql

```
//note table

heading  varchar(300)   YES     
body     varchar(5000)  YES     
noteid   char(36)       NO   PRI    
authorID char(36)       YES  MUL    
color    char(7)        YES     
style    varchar(100)   YES 

 
//user table


userid      char(36)        NO  PRI 
email       varchar(255)    YES     
password    varchar(255)    YES     
username    varchar(255)    YES
```

I am trying to add a **forign**  key in user table

```
ALTER TABLE user
ADD FOREIGN KEY (noteid) REFERENCES note (noteid);
```

But it is showing me an error

```
Error Code: 1072. Key column 'noteid' doesn't exist in table
```

What i am doing wrong

Comment: `noteid` is in the `note` table, not the `user` table. Did you intend to clone it in both places? The foreign key might suggest that.

Comment: i also tried id instead of noteid but it stills give error that id does not exsist in table

Comment: Because you have to provide a column in `user` that will match the primary key column in `note`. `user` does not contain a column named `noteid` nor a column named `id` so the command fails.

Comment: can you please give an example thanks :)

Comment: Just add a column to `user` that will correspond to `note.noteid`. You can name it whatever you want, but to match your original SQL command you would call it `noteid`.